# How do I test and validate a Markov Model in RStudio?

Tags: r, markov-process, rstudio, markov-hidden-model

I've created a Markov Model in RStudio using the seqHMM library. I'm new to R and would usually do this kind of thing in Python, but I wanted to use seqHMM. I can see the model has been created and it plots successfully. However, how do I run some test / validation data through it (some more sequence data)?

```
library(seqHMM)
library(TraMineR)
print("Sequence prediction")

house_seq <- read.csv(file = "train_test.csv", header = TRUE)
# Print the first 3 observations
head(house_seq, 3)
dim(house_seq)

# Define a color palette for the sequence data
attr(house_seq, "cpal") <- colorpalette[[6]]

# Estimate the Markov model
mm_house <- build_mm(observations = seqdef(house_seq$noun))
plot(mm_house)
```